# Hawaiian Checkers in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

Hi so I've been trying to make the game Konane (hawaiian checkers) In Android Studio with 0 experience in it, and I've come to a bit of a roadblock regarding the movement of pieces.

Before I get into that here are the rules:

The game begins with all the counters filling the board in an alternating pattern of black and white. Players then hop over one another's pieces, capturing them similar to checkers. The first player unable to capture is the loser; his opponent is the winner.

https://gyazo.com/e01443d09f75df1a764842c98a220a09
The link above is pretty much all I have right now.

Right now Instead of having pieces I am just using buttons and I want to be able to click them and click on a blank space and execute the move, removing the piece inbetween and moving the original piece to the blank spot.

I was wondering if anyone could offer any advice on how I can do this; I don't have much experience with Android Studio or Java really and am pretty stumped as to how I should do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways

The best would be if you check if button clicked on the middle button between 2 buttons, 1 clicked and one not.

You need to constantly check if the button is clicked.

Assign booleans to each space on the board and you can see which is clicked and which is not.